# Is the entire ciphertext needed for decryption with key?

Tags: encryption, decryption

Lets say that you have they encryption key, but you don't have the entire cipher-text. You just have a part of it, say 60%.

Is there a way to possibly decrypt that part of the cipher-text? Does it depend on the specific algorithm or mode? Does it depend on the specific forms of data like text and not image form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, regarding the encryption algorithm, there are two general types of algorithms, blocks and chains. A block algorithm applies the key to each block of data (e.g. 256 bit blocks), while a chained algorithm uses the previous block to decode the current block, with the key serving as the first block in the chain. For the block algorithm, you can decrypt every block that you have access to. The chain algorithm, however, will not be able to go any further than the first missing block, so if the 60% of the data you have doesn't include the first block, it's not possible to decrypt any of the the data, even with the key.

Next, once you get whatever data you get back, what you can process depends on the file format. For a plain text file, you can read whatever parts you were able to decode. More complicated file formats may or may not be readable. For example, GIF will break as soon as you have a byte you can't decode correctly, while formats like JPEG and MP4 are generally recoverable except for the missing frames, and ZIP can usually recover files as long as the files and some critical data structures are present.

So, there's really three possible outcomes: you can't decrypt the data at all, you can decrypt the data but can't parse it at all, or you can decrypt the data and recover useful information. It really depends on the encryption's algorithm and the payload contained in the data.

Comment: As I said, it depends on the algorithm. GIF uses a scan-based top-down approach, so as soon as you miss a byte of data, you're done. PNG can use an interlaced format, so if you have 50% of the data, you can probably see a blurry (2x2 pixelated) image, and if you have JPEG, you'll probably be able to get back the 8x8 blocks that JPEG uses for whatever data you have. The choice of format is key.

Comment: wouldnt desynchronisation be another factor

Comment: @sweetpunk Again, it depends on the format you're talking about. Some formats insert regular "tags" or "magic markers" that allow resynchronization to occur later in the data stream if bytes are missing. Most well-structured formats consider some small range of data acceptable loss. For example, you can generally recover a frame or part thereof of an animated GIF as long as you can find the header bytes. The same is true of most movie formats as well. If the format doesn't allow resynchronization, though, it could obviously be an issue; it's still format dependent.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Phyrfox's answer, it also depends on the data. If the data has any forward error correction (like a hamming code) included in it then some missing parts of the data can be re created. If it was something like a plain text password, or a part of a shared secret you would have to guess the missing parts. And if it were another encrypted message you may not be able to decrypt any of that at all.

So depending on the type of encryption and data you could get all, some, or none of the data out from a partial cipher text.

Comment: I think there's some better example than an encrypted message inside an encrypted message for when 1 missing bit of the cyphertext means none of the message is recoverable but i can't remember what that idea is called.